# Remove Lines in VIM with Only Whitespace

Tags: vim, whitespace

Is there a vim idiom for removing all lines from a file that have only whitespace (including newlines)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d` command takes a range, and the range can be a regex.

```
:g/^\s*$/d
```

Comment: so, normally I use something like `:%s/search/replace/g` to do global search and replace.  is `:g` equivalent to `:%s` with g option?

Comment: `:` puts vim in command mode. `g` is a modifier for the range. `%` is the range that means "all lines". `s` is the substitute command. `d` is the delete command, which takes no options.

Comment: @Ignacio: On first read I saw that `d` takes *no hostages* ...

Comment: @honk: Unfortunately it does. Fortunately they're only a `p` away.

Comment: `:g[lobal]` applies an ex command to the lines that match a given pattern. So, in the given solution `:global` will search for lines with 0 or more white space (`/^\s*$/`) and apply the `:d[elete]` command on them. See `:h :global` for more details and alternatives.

Comment: the :v version of :g is also very useful since it applies the command to the lines that don't match the pattern.  For example the same could be accomplished with the following: :v/\S/d